# Add data to dynamic array name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to add data to an array using JavaScript/Vue.js.

Well, this is no problem:

```
methods: {
    add: function add(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!this.newName) return;

        this.config.names.firstnames.push(this.newName);
        this.newName = '';
    },
}
```

But: I would like to make `this.config.names.firstnames` dynamic.

If this`.type == "firstnames"` the data should be added to  `this.config.names.firstnames`. If `this.type == "lastnames"` the data should be added to `this.config.names.lastnames`. So the element to push to should be the value of `this.type`.

How can I solve that the most elegant way?

Comment: `most elegant` is subjective and not a question for SO, however, have you tried anything yet? Even something exactly as you described: `if(this.type == "firstnames"){this.config.names.firstnames.push(this.newName);}; if(this.type == "lastnames"){this.config.names.lastnames.push(this.newName);}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `type` is exactly correlated to the key on the names object you can use the bracket notation:

`this.config.names[this.type].push(this.newName)`